# AccessDeniendException on copying from GCP Compute instance to Storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, permissions, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, gsutil

I want to copy an object from a Google Compute Engine instance to a Google Storage Bucket using `gsutil cp`. Both belong to the same owner (me) and to the same project. I want to automate the whole machine so authenticating manually is not what I want.

I have activated the [necessary permissions](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/iam-gsutil) to use a service account on a Compute instance (details below) but when I try to `gsutil cp` a file to the bucket, I get an `AccessDeniedException`.
The error message complains about missing `storage.object.create` or `storage.object.list` permissions depending on if my bucket target path ends in a folder (`gs://<bucket>/test/`) or file (`gs://<bucket>/test.txt`).

What I did to get permissions (I have already tried a *lot*, including creating redundant custom roles which I also assigned to the service account):

- Start the instance:

```
gcloud instances create <instance> [...] \
    --service--account <name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --scopes cloud-platform,storage-full
```

- Give the service account permissions on creation.
- Give the service account permissions afterwards as well (just to be safe):

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding <project> \
    --member serviceAccount:<name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role roles/storage.objectAdmin
```

- Edit Storage bucket permissions for the service account:

```
gsutil iam ch \
    serviceAccount:<name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:roles/storage.objectAdmin \
    gs://<bucket>
```

- Edit Storage bucket access control list (owner permission):

```
gsutil acl ch -u <name>@<project>.iam.gserviceaccount.com:O gs://<bucket>
```

- At some point enabled bucket-level IAM policies instead of per-object policies (just to be safe).
- On the instance, use
  `gcloud auth activate-service-account --key-file <key>.json` to authenticate the account.

However, no matter, what I do, the error does not change and I am not able to write to the bucket. I *can*, however, read files from the bucket. I also get the same error on a local machine using the service account, so the problem is not related to instances.

Comment: Are you rebooting your instance after changing the service account?

Answer (score 0):

As well as ensuring that the service account that you're using has appropriate permissions, you also need to ensure that the instance you're using has the appropriate scopes to access Google Cloud Storage, which they usually don't be default. You can either set the scopes to `Allow full access to all Cloud APIs` or set them individually if you'd prefer. You can find instructions on how to do so [here](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes).

Comment: Isn't that what I do when starting the instance using `--scopes cloud-platform,storage-full`?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new service account and executed the exact same steps... Now it works.